# Handling copy paste events in SharePoint 2013 JSGrid

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jslink, xslt-list-view-web-part

Any idea how we can handle the copy paste events into the JSGrid. In IE we can copy from excel and paste(like in excel). I need to validate some columns on bulk paste. However none of the handlers are being called when its pasted from clip board.

I was successful in handling events when value of cell was individually changed(manually). However bulk copy paste seems to be trickier.

Comment: Have you tried to copy and paste the same data twice?
We found this workaround by accident.